# After clicking on "Load more" I can't smoothly transfer to the beginning of the fetched pictures

Tags: javascript, rest, scroll

The page should automatically scroll smoothly after rendering the images exactly on one screen in order to transfer the user to the beginning of the fetched images.

```
refs.button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  api.pageNum++;
  getResults(refs.input.value, api.pageNum);
  window.scrollTo({
    top: window.innerHeight,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
});
```

Comment: please provide some example on stackblitz or jsbin

Comment: use this function for smooth scroll https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView